# Is it possible to access sms functionality via j2me?

Tags: windows-phone-7, java-me, sms-gateway, midp-2.0

Hi i am developing windows mobile application for dopod 818 pro to send / receive sms.

is it possible to access sms functionality via j2me?

Comment: These two sentences conflict.

Comment: Are you sure about the "Windows Phone 7" tag? Java isn't available on that platform. You probably meant Windows Mobile 6.

Answer (score 0):

You can not read SMS from Inbox directly. For reading SMS from Inbox you need [APIBridge.jar](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Tools_and_downloads/Other/APIBridge/). APIBridge is an extensible mechanism to access device features in WRT, Flash Lite, and Java applications.

You can use APIBridge in two ways. APIBridge can be used as it is shipped, to access features of Symbian using the plug-ins provided. However, because APIBridge is based on a plug-in architecture, you can also use it to offer new features by creating plug-ins that access functions of Symbian or your own native Symbian applications.

Please note that APIBridge.jar works for Symbian OS Based Phone Only. **Not for S40 Device**.